# Can someone help me change this php query to get all fields in one shot?

Tags: php

I have this shopping cart script that is run in a loop, but when i try to email it i only allows me to email 9 items anything more than 9 items the email just comes in blank. I was told that i should change my query `'SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = '.$id;` to one that will return all items without the loop. Is this correct and what i should try to do? if so could someone give me a example of how i would do that?

```
<?php
function showCarts() {
global $db;
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
if ($cart) {
$items = explode(',',$cart);
$contents = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1;
}
$output[] = '<table style="border-width:1px; bordercolor="#0099FF"">';
    $output[] = '<tr>';
    $output[] = '<thead bgcolor="#0099FF">';
    $output[] = '<th>Item</th>';
    $output[] = '<th>Price</th>';
    $output[] = '<th>Quantity</th>';
    $output[] = '<th>Total</th>';
    $output[] = '</thead>';
    $output[] = '</tr>';
            foreach ($contents as $id=>$qty) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = '.$id;
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch();
    extract($row);
    $output[] = '<tr>';
    $output[] = '<td>'.$title.' by '.$author.'</td>';
    $output[] = '<td>&dollar;'.$price.'</td>';
    $output[] = '<td>'.$qty.'</td>';
    $output[] = '<td>&dollar;'.($price * $qty).'</td>';
    $total += ($price * $qty);
    $output[] = '</tr>';
}
$output[] = '</table>';
$tax = (.07);
$taxtotal += round($total * $tax,2);
$amounttotal += ($total + $taxtotal);
$output[] = '<p>Tax: <strong>&dollar;'.$taxtotal.'</strong></p>';
$output[] = '<p>Total: <strong>&dollar;'.$amounttotal.'</strong></p>';
}
return join('',$output);
}
?>
```

Comment: `WHERE id=?` N times is always way slower than `WHERE id IN (?,?,...?)` with N values.

Comment: *sidenote:* Incorrect HTML: `<table style="border-width:1px; bordercolor="#0099FF"">`

Comment: Careful, it is likely that you are open to SQL injection and XSS attacks.  Always use prepared/parameterized queries for databases, and `htmlspecialchars()` around arbitrary data used in the context of HTML.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for the heads up on that, do you have any suggestions on how i could prevent any sql injections?

Comment: @user2426617, Yes, please read my comment again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your for-loop part with :

```
    $ids = implode(',', array_keys($contents));
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN ('. $ids . ')';
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch()) {
      extract($row);
      $qty = $contents[(int)$row['id']]; // assuming your `$row` is an associative array of result
      $output[] = '<tr>';
      $output[] = '<td>'.$title.' by '.$author.'</td>';
      $output[] = '<td>&dollar;'.$price.'</td>';
      $output[] = '<td>'.$qty.'</td>';
      $output[] = '<td>&dollar;'.($price * $qty).'</td>';
      $total += ($price * $qty);
      $output[] = '</tr>';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, This does work well, but i still get a blank email when i add more than 9 items to the cart. I add the showCart() function to the body of my email script to email the cart. Is there anyway to do this without a loop at all?

Comment: the problem is elsewhere. Check your maximum post size. You may exceed the size limit.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer above, i have checked my max_post_size and it is 50M and my memory_limit is only 20M, do you think this is sufficient? Also I use yahoo as my host and i do not have access to my php.ini file nor the .htaccess any suggestions on how to get around that?